# Databricks auto_termination is set to 60 minutes, and my job fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, databricks

I have a notebook created in databricks, and I would like to run this job on-demand from AWS Lambda.  That is, when a file arrives in my S3 bucket, i would like to run databricks notebook job for my ETL purpose.

The databricks cluster has **autotermination_minutes** parameter set for 60 minutes.  Sometimes my job is not running, since the cluster auto-terminates when its idle for 60 minutes.  Is there any way I can restart the cluster from AWS Lambda before running the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, using Databricks Cluster APIs.
You just need to pass the cluster-id.

Here is the link
https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/clusters.html#start

Comment: Thanks, I saw it and have tried it. Am getting PERMISSION issues, so once the access is granted, sure, this would work. Thx.